# Yii2 file kit не правильно проставляет индексы

Tags: php, yii2

Суть вот в чём: 
Загружаю файлы через https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-file-kit 
На выходе получается так, что грузит все файлы, но я не могу их сохранить так как индексы для инпутов не проставляются больше 1. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно. 
`image[0]` и два `image[1]`

Загрузи я 100 файлов - будет первый с индексом 0, А остальные с 1.

Код виджета:

`<?php echo $form->field($model, 'images')->widget(
        \trntv\filekit\widget\Upload::class,
    [
        'url' => ['/file/storage/upload'], 
        'maxNumberOfFiles' => 10,
    ]
    ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Решения не нашел. 
Решил через свой форк... 
https://github.com/crocone/yii2-file-kit